# Upgrade bugzilla on local machine (3.4.x to 4.2.x)

Tags: perl, bazaar, bugzilla

I've installed bugzilla **Win32InstallPackages**

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32InstallPackages

its pretty easy, just download **Bugzilla-Setup-3.4.8.exe** file, follow steps and keep pressing Next button. It installs everything (Apache, MySql, Perl, Bugzilla) and works perfect. Just start using bugzilla through this url localhost

Now I want to upgrade this with some stable latest release which is 4.4. I am using Bazaar repository to download at my local PC from here  http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/4.4/

Bazaar explorer creates trunk folder inside C:\Bugzilla\trunk and downloaded all source code inside the trunk directory.

When I've copied all the files from trunk folder and replaced with existing files at C:\Bugzilla\ then it doesn't work.

Now I am getting following error message when I am trying to open bugzilla by writing localhost/ into address bar.

```
500 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Could you please help me how to upgrade bugzilla on my local machine ?

Answer (score 0):

There are [upgrade instructions](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/upgrade.html) that can be followed. Also check your apache logs to find out what the 500 error is really about.